# Could not set Option bytes! Please reset the target and retry

Tags: stm32, stm32f1

When I try to remove the Read Out Protection from stm32f103c8t6 I get an error

```
Could not set Option bytes! Please reset the target and retry.
```

[image]

Сonnect like this:

[image]

The problem is not in the controller, as it is completely new. Please tell me what I'm doing wrong